# Restarting multiprocessing if exception is thrown in any running processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am wondering how I could restart a multiprocessing task if an exception is thrown in any of its running processes?

I am calling three instances of the same function, which are running tasks independently on a large, but finite dataset.

If an exception is thrown for any of the three processes, the other processes will continue, but the computing power is diminished. I am wondering how I could detect a failure (i.e. an exception) in any of the processes and reboot the multiprocessing task entirely?

Here is a snippet of the code below - in this example, I am running the  function *example_func* that takes in a list as an argument:

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func, args=([],))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func, args=([],))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func, args=([],))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

Also, is there a better way of designing this multiprocessing task? I am operating on three cores, here - but I believe there is a more elegant way to queue this...

Comment: Have you looked into using `Pool` in `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Put your exception handler into your function `example_func` and do the restarting there. No other to do that right from the outside. `multiprocessing.Pool` is the right choice if you have a simple task, but is less flexible.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you cddt and RaJa. I will take a look at multiprocessing.Pool and refactor the function to better catch exceptions.